# Is using Paypal Adaptive Payments API for Mobile Web right choice?

Tags: paypal, mobile-website, paypal-adaptive-payments, express-checkout

Here is bit more about my requirement.

I am working on the mobile website project for games. Where people can host games and sell digital goods/game items. We don't want users to leave our website, even while paying. Yes, only want to use Paypal for checkout experience. (So we can keep discussions on Paypal scope.)

Paypal mobile express checkout : It redirects users to Paypal for payment confirmation, and bring back after payments completes / cancels. Also on every purchase user needs to authenticate himself. (Correct me if I have wrong understanding. I have read documentation from Paypal.)

Paypal Adaptive payments : It allows more handle over user experience, It pops up Paypal dialog in Mini-browser or Light box. Works very well on desktop and Mobile apps. (According to my research, haven't implemented yet.).

Can we use Adaptive payments for Mobile web? More interested in Pre-Approval payment flow. Anybody has experience working on it? Please share your experience and  challenges you had to face.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  I've used Preapproved Payments and Pay with jQuery Mobile apps and it works quite nicely.

One cool thing, too, is that if payer approves you can actually take new payments in real-time without interrupting their game play.